# A question about percentages of acid solution being added to more acid solutions.

Tags: percentages

how many liters of an 80% acid solution must be mixed with a 15% acid solution to get 390L of a 70% acid solution?

I'm taking a math prep class in college and I never learned this stuff in high school. The professor wont help me

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let x = ml of 80% solution added, y = ml of 15% solution added. From there we can write down two equations.

$$\begin{eqnarray}x &+ y &= 390 \\
0.8x &+ 0.15y &= 0.70 \times 390.\end{eqnarray}$$

Are you okay to solve it from there?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\text{Percent}& \text{Total Solution} & \text{Acid}  \\ \hline
80\% & x  & (0.8)x  \\ \hline
15\% & 390-x & (0.15)(390-x)  \\ \hline
70\% & 390 & (0.70)390  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

You can see we are adding the top two lines to get the bottom line.  The acid must add up so you can say $$(0.8)x+(0.15)(390-x)=(0.7)390$$